# Not able to understand Fragment replace, role of FrameLayout and where does it fall in place

Tags: android, android-fragments

In one of my fragment I have the below layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="matrix"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner_dashboard" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/settings_nested" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now the following:

```
  <include layout="@layout/settings_nested" />
```

Consists of some buttons, on click of one such button I want to replace the framelayout with new contents - new fragment which has a different layout. Here is how I do it:

```
 Fragment fragment = null;
                fragment = new FragmentEmails();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.email_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now I can see the optionsMenu change when I click the button (As I have defined a different menu file for this new Fragment) However the contents remain the same. Advice any? I think I am doing something wrong the way I am defining the framlayout as the parent of my views, but what exactly, beats me.

Comment: Try to remove all the contents of `email_container`.

Comment: Hey but those children are the layout elements of my first fragment, where do I place them? Outside Frame Layout?

Comment: Fragment is used to replace the layouts, here in your code the frame layout is a container of the replacing layouts. Fragment uses the same base activity and override the last frame with the new fragment and fragment is not needed to be declare at manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my Thoughts and Views, You should Do as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the Parent Layout of all fragment and email_container will be used for the transactions of other fragments.

then Create another layout that consists of the inner elements that i have erased.

on startup what you want to display , Change this email_container inneer elements with another fragment like

```
 Fragment fragmentStartPage = null;
                fragmentStartPage = new FragmentEmails();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.email_container, fragmentStartPage);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

then change it with another fragment by replacing the fragmentStartPage with another fragment.

Comment: This is a nice idea. I will implement this and get back!